# Spark datagrid with checkbox does not update correctly

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, datagrid, flex-spark

The checkboxes are updated correctly when I select one or more datagrid rows but when I select a checkbox for the first time the checkbox does not refresh until the pointer moves out of the datagrid row. How can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:DataGrid id="dg" x="344" y="48" selectionMode="multipleRows" requestedRowCount="4">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn>
                    <s:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        import mx.controls.Alert;
                                        import spark.components.DataGrid;

                                        override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void
                                        {
                                            cb.selected = grid.selectionContainsIndex(rowIndex);
                                        }
                                    ]]>
                                </fx:Script>
                                <s:CheckBox id="cb" label="" horizontalCenter="0"/>
                            </s:GridItemRenderer>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </s:itemRenderer>
                </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField1" headerText="Column 1"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField2" headerText="Column 2"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField3" headerText="Column 3"></s:GridColumn>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
        <s:typicalItem>
            <fx:Object dataField1="Sample Data" dataField2="Sample Data" dataField3="Sample Data"></fx:Object>
        </s:typicalItem>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:Object dataField1="data1" dataField2="data1" dataField3="data1"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object dataField1="data2" dataField2="data2" dataField3="data2"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object dataField1="data3" dataField2="data3" dataField3="data3"></fx:Object>
            <fx:Object dataField1="data4" dataField2="data4" dataField3="data4"></fx:Object>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just fake the `CheckBox` by drawing a `CheckBox` shape in the `ItemRenderer` and use the states to show the tick.

```
<s:GridItemRenderer>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="hovered" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- checkbox graphics -->
    <s:Group width="16" height="16" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xffffff" />
            </s:fill>
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xa9aeb2" />
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- tick, only shown when selected -->
        <s:Rect includeIn="selected" width="8" height="8" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0x90b40c" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

This is a simplified graphic for a checkbox, but you can go grab the code from the spark `CheckBoxSkin` and copy/paste it in the `itemrenderer`. Just might have to change some state names.

This will not deselect a single row though when you hit the `CheckBox` of an already selected row, unless you hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key down. That's the default behavior of the `DataGrid` component. I'm afraid you'll have to create your own subclass of `DataGri`d if you want to prevent that behavior.

Another important thing to know: setting the `selected` property on the `itemrenderers` doesn't change the `selectIndices` of the `DataGrid`. Hence on the next `commitProperties()` cycle the value you set in the renderer will be overridden by the `DataGrid`.

**Old answer:** (before edit)

The `ItemRenderer` class (and thus the `GridItemRenderer` class too) has a `selected` property.
So you could bind the checkboxes `selected` property to the `itemrenders`, like so:

```
<s:CheckBox selected="{selected}" horizontalCenter="0" />
```

You'd have to create a separate `ItemRenderer` class for that to work though instead of an inline one.
If you absolutely want to go the inline way you can always override the `selected` setter.

```
<s:GridItemRenderer>
  <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
      override public function set selected(value:Boolean):void {
          super.selected = cb.selected = value;
      }
  ]]>
  </fx:Script>
  <s:CheckBox id="cb" horizontalCenter="0"/>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thanks RIAstar. Binding the checkboxes 'selected' property to GridItemRenderer works fine but the opposite doesn't seem to work.

The checkbox doesn't update correctly when I select it and I can only select one checkbox at a time.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I did solve this issue once though. Let me go dig in my code for a sec and then I'll come back with a solution.

Comment: Sure. I added it as an edit of my original answer yesterday. Look up ;) I thought the system would notify you about that, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks again :) I also found another solution on an adobe blog. In case you are interested http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2011/03/spark-checkbox-datagrid-with-drag-and-drop-support.html

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
 <s:CheckBox id="cb" label="" horizontalCenter="0"/>
```

To:

```
<s:CheckBox id="cb" label="" horizontalCenter="0" enabled="false"/>
```

I just recommend you to use enabled property.

I think the dispatched "click event" from both `checkbox` and `gridColumn`, then returned function prevented each other.

If enabled property set false, your click event dispathed on only `gridColumn` then using `cb.selected=grid.selectionContainsIndex(rowIndex);` correctly occupy if you want to show checkbox enabled, you can use `CSS` or `skinclass`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just use the renders selected state as suggested by RIAStar. However if you are using global skinning doing the custom drawing does not work, use either a skinnable container or as I have just put the checkbox in there but dont make it respond to mouse commands. For the multi selection, as long as your grid is setup to multiple rows or columns you can simply capture the mouse events and force the ctrl key which makes them handle multi select.

```
<s:GridItemRenderer 
    mouseDown="mouseDownHandler(event)"
    mouseUp="mouseUpHandler(event)"
    buttonMode="true"
    mouseChildren="false"
    useHandCursor="true"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    >

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="selected"/>
    </s:states>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                event.ctrlKey = true;
            }

            protected function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                event.ctrlKey = true;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:CheckBox 
        id="check"
        selected.normal="false"
        selected.selected="true"
        horizontalCenter="0"
        verticalCenter="0"
        />

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up simply doing this:

```
            <s:GridColumn dataField="myBoolean" headerText="Returned" width="55">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                <s:CheckBox id="cb1" selected="{data.myBoolean}" change="{data.myBoolean=cb1.selected}"/>                                                           
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
```