# Checkbox in dynamically generated DataGrid - how to retrieve selected value

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, checkbox

I want to have a column in my dataGrid with checkboxes in it. My code that creates grid with the column looks like this:

```
var dataGrid:DataGrid=new DataGrid();
var preparedColumns:Array=[];
preparedColumns.push(new DataGridColumn("DepCode"));
var checkboxColumn:DataGridColumn=new DataGridColumn("AddSegment");
checkboxColumn.itemRenderer=new ClassFactory(CheckBox);
checkboxColumn.editable=true;
preparedColumns.push(checkboxColumn);

for (var i:int=0; i < event.result.request.out.segments.segment.length; i++)
{
    var segment:Object=event.result.request.out.segments.segment[i];
    var addSegmentCheckbox:CheckBox=new CheckBox();
    preparedValues.addItem({DepCode: segment.departureCode, AddSegment: addSegmentCheckbox});
    addSegmentCheckbox.id = ""+i;
    addSegmentCheckbox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeCheckboxState);
    checkboxValues[i] = false;
}
dataGrid.columns=preparedColumns;
dataGrid.dataProvider=preparedValues;
```

This works, at least it renders what I want but I can't figure out how to read if user selected checkbox in given row or not. I've seen that often there are added function onChange to the checkbox but I can't figure out how to do it when I use factory (most examples I found don't create itemRenderer in code but with the use of tags).

I tried to read data like this but checkbox.selected turn out to be false no matter if I checked the checkbox or not.

```
public function OKButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var i:int=0; i < preparedValues.length; i++)
    {
        var row:Object=preparedValues[i];
        var checkbox:CheckBox=row.AddSegment;
        if (checkbox.selected == true)
        {           
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add a listener for checkboxes as suggested in the loop but the listener method isn't executed when checkboxes states change (I checked it in debugger). I updated the first code part above and added following method:

public function changeCheckboxState(event:Event):void
{
    var i:int = event.currentTarget.id;
        if (checkboxValues[i] == true) {
            checkboxValues[i] == false;
        } else {
        checkboxValues[i] == true;
        } 
}

Table checkboxValues never changes (I set it up all to false at the beginning) and the above method is never executed.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't have to access ItemRenderers. You should rather create a custom itemrenderer and bind the selection of the checkbox to a property of the underlying data record. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146006/spark-datagrid-with-checkbox-does-not-update-correctly/6146070#6146070

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for `Event.CHANGE` instead of for the mouse click itself (that way you know you're getting the event after the framework has updated `selected`).

From there, you should be able to get the owner of the checkbox (as an `ItemRenderer`), and retrieve the data for that cell.

Comment: I upteded my question but have problems with adding event listener.